# Azure DevOps - Multiple projects with multiple Kanban boards vs Single Project with multiple repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm thinking to move to Azure DevOps. But I'm at the stage where it's hard to decide which option will be useful.

My Requirements:

1. Single dashboard for the current sprint to have transparency to
   everyone in the team. No context switching.
2. Single backlog for all projects.
3. User stories & bug will be easily identified by project.
4. Reports by projects, teams, etc.
5. Service hooks - Microsoft teams, etc.
6. Source control - GIT.
7. Artifacts.
8. Test plans under one board.

I'm thinking of going with single project(multiple repositories)

But before going down this road I just want to know what are the pros and cons of both options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we recommend that you use a single project to support your organization or enterprise. A single project minimizes the maintenance of administrative tasks and supports the most optimized / full-flexibility [cross-link object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=azure-devops) experience.

Even if you have many teams working on hundreds of different applications and software projects, you can most easily manage them within a single project. A project serves to isolate data stored within it. You can't easily move data from one project to another. When you move data from one project to another, you typically lose the history associated with that data.

So according to your situation, it is recommended to use a single project with multiple repos and multiple teams. For details you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops#when-to-add-another-project).

**Reasons to add another project**

You may want to add another project in following instances:

- To prohibit or manage access to the information contained within a
  project to select groups
- To support custom work tracking processes for specific business units
  within your organization
- To support entirely separate business units that have their own
  administrative policies and administrators
- To support testing customization activities or adding extensions
  before rolling out changes to the working project
- To support an Open Source Software (OSS) project

Answer (score 0):

And how about these limits?

- A long text field can contain 1M characters.
- You can't assign more than 100 tags to a work item.
- You can't add more than 1,000 links to a work item.
- You can't add more than 100 attachments to a work item.
- You can't add an attachment size larger than 60 MB to a work item.
- You can have up to 1,000 tasks on a task board
- **You can have up to 10,000 work items on a backlog**
- You are limited to 5,000 teams in a project
- You can't create more than 150,000 tag definitions per project

If this is true, put all organization projects inside a single project could become a really big problem (at least for my organization). Or I am missing something?

Comment: Hi 
Your answer brings an important consideration of possible limitations to the discussion, however it's more suited as a comment rather then a complete answer to the question posted

Comment: "Each backlog can display up to 10,000 work items. This is a limit on what the backlog can display, not a limit on the number of work items you can define. If your backlog exceeds this limit, then you may want to consider adding a team and moving some of the work items to the other team's backlog."